# Silverlight 4 nested ListBox controls performance issue

Tags: silverlight, performance, listbox, nested

I am working on a silverlight page that will have a horizontal list box that will contain a list of "cards". Each "card" contains a vertical list box with some text in it. However, I am running into a lot of performance issues. Has anyone experienced any performance issues with nested listboxes in the past?

Comment: Some idea of volumes would help, how many items in the horizontal list box?  How many of them are visible at one time?  How many items in each vertical list box?  Are you specifying your own items panel?

Answer (score 1):

If its a DataGrid then Paging can give good performance. If its ListBox then we should keep an eye on the count of data binded with listbox.

Are you trying to bind the full list on single shot from server ? Then this will definitely affect the performance.

Comment: I am binding to a list generated in the constructor. The list of cards is only 20 items, and the vertical sub list in each list box item consists of only 25 list box items of plain text. However, the performance is awful.

Answer (score 0):

UI Virtualization might help you. Try to use VirtualizingStackPanel (instead of StackPanel) as the ItemsPanel of your Listbox:

```
<ListBox>
    ...
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```